# if derivative at a point is not invertible, then there is no local differentiable inverse in a neighborhood of that point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the following, let **f**: W $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $W \subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ , be a differentiable function, and let $\mathbf{x_{0}
}$ be a point in W, if $[D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})] $ is not invertible at that point, then $\mathbf{f}$ does not have a local inverse around $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{{x_0}})$. Here is my procedure until now:

if $\mathbf{f^{-1}}$ exists in a neighborhood V of $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{{x_0}})$, and it is differentiable, then for all $\mathbf{x}$ in the range
of  $\mathbf{f^{-1}}$, we have by the chain rule:

\begin{eqnarray}
I_{n}&=&[D(\mathbf{f^{-1} \circ f})(\mathbf{x})] \\
 &=& [D\mathbf{f^{-1}}(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}))][D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})] 
\end{eqnarray}

In particular, for $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x_0}$, $I_n = [D\mathbf{f^{-1}}(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}))][D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0})]$, however the previous result is not possible, since by hypothesis, $[D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})] $ is not invertible.

However, i am not sure if the previous contradiction guarantees that there is no local differentiable inverse of $\mathbf{f}$.

Comment: You assumed that there were a local differentiable inverse of $f$. You then derived a contradiction. You are now finished.